# What's JSON prefix used for?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I know it is a stupid question but I did not find expected answer by Google. One of new feature of Spring MVC 4.3 is supporting to configure JSON prefix

```
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="jsonPrefix" value=")]}',\n" />
    </bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
```

So the JSON input/output can look like:

```
)]}',\n"{\"userName\":\"ABC\",\"emailId\":\"ABC@gmail.com\"}"
```

I know it is for the security purpose. But what is it about concretely?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at another method added [setPrefixJson(boolean) in the Spring JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html#setPrefixJson-boolean-) you'll understand the reasoning behind it:

> Indicate whether the JSON output by this view should be prefixed with ")]}', ". Default is false.
>
> Prefixing the JSON string in this manner is used to help prevent JSON
>   Hijacking. The prefix renders the string syntactically invalid as a
>   script so that it cannot be hijacked. This prefix should be stripped
>   before parsing the string as JSON.