# API returns garbage characters before the actual data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Has anyone seen something like this before? I am not sure why `)]}'` is added before the actual Json and I am not sure if it is specific to our application only. I just want to get some ideas. Thank you.

```
)]}',
{
    "id": 1
}
```

Comment: It's a JSON prefix. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082479

Comment: OK, I get to cross off my _"You learn something new every day"_ item from today's list